# Marker click not detected with Talkback ON - Android SDK v8.6.1

Tags: android, mapbox-android, talkback, mapbox-marker

Android not detecting a click on the marker with **accessibility Talkback ON** in SDK version 8.6.1. It is detecting click for entire mapview, info element but not markers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `queryRenderedFeatures()` to query a map layer and then read the `Feature` property info from any `Feature`(s) returned by the method.

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/query/

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/search?q=queryRenderedFeatures&unscoped_q=queryRenderedFeatures